# Inner join should be optional

Tags: mysql, sql

From my table `personal` I would like to join the tables `languages` and `payment`:

```sql
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT languages.language) AS languages, personal.city, payment.before 
FROM personal 
INNER JOIN languages ON languages.uid = personal.uid 
INNER JOIN payment ON payment.uid = personal.uid 
WHERE personal.uid = 36
```

The return of my query is:

```
| languages   |  city          | before  |
|-------------|:--------------:|--------:|
| NULL        |  NULL          | NULL    |
```

This is because there is no record in my table `payment`. Is there a way to make the 4th line of my code optional? So if `payment.uid = personal.uid` would be false, the result should look like this:

```
| languages   |  city          | before  |
|-------------|:--------------:|--------:|
| English     |  Chicago       | NULL    |
```

Comment: ***Optional*** `INNER JOIN` is called `OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: Can there be no records in `languages`? Should there be a result for them?

Comment: @Barmar yes, `languages` could also be empty without any rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` so you always get a row:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT l.language) AS languages, p.city, pa.before 
FROM personal p LEFT JOIN
     languages l
     ON l.uid = p.uid LEFT JOIN
     payment pa
     ON pa.uid = p.uid 
WHERE p.uid = 36
GROUP BY p.city, pa.before;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- You have an aggregation query with bare columns in the `SELECT` that are not in the `GROUP BY`.  This is bad SQL -- and not allowed (with the default settings) in the more recent versions of MySQL.  Learn to properly structure your `GROUP BY` queries.
- This will return no rows if no row matches `p.uid = 36`.  However, it will return a row if that exists, even if no rows exist in the other tables.

Comment: Thank you for the solution and the further information. They help me a lot!